# XML compare tool that can "Tidy" the XML and ignore differences in attributes

Tags: xml, comparison

I am looking at using **Beyond Compare 3** with *XML Tidy* compare comparison format.  *XML Tidy* formats all the nodes with **proper line breaks and indentation** if an XML file is all slopped onto one line.  ...So I would love a tool that can do this and can **ignore differences in attributes**, or not even show attributes at all (this is because attributes are irrelevant to my users).

Is there a tool that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT identity transform that omits the attributes and sets the output to indent should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```